# AS3 Error 1009 null object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, null

I have no idea why it keeps saying Error 1009!?

Here the code

```
    import flash.events.Event;

    var mysound:Sound = new Avondbos(); 
    var channel1:SoundChannel = mysound.play();


    start.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, veeg);
    start.buttonMode = true;

    function veeg (e:Event):void
    {
        maan.gotoAndPlay("2");
        start.gotoAndPlay("2");
        headphone.gotoAndPlay("2");
        rupsje.gotoAndPlay("2");
    }

    maan.land.blad.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, klikblad);
    maan.land.blad.buttonMode = true;

    function klikblad(e:Event):void
    {
        if (maan.land.blad.currentFrameLabel == "halfblad")
        Object(root).gotoAndStop(1, "Cocon2");
    }

    maan.land.blad.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, klikblad2);

    function klikblad2(e:Event):void
    {
        maan.land.blad.gotoAndPlay("130");
        rupsje.gotoAndPlay("293");
}
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Project_550690_Robin_Janssen_fla::MainTimeline/klikblad2()
```

Can't figure out what I do wrong and Flash is not helping either.

Thanks in advance,

Robin

Comment: I think that you are new on stackoverflow, so welcome. The famous #1009 Error ! So here the compiler is speaking about a null object in your `klikblad2` function, so what you can do is going to that function and verifying your objects : it's simple, you have two lines, disable the first one, if you still get the error, so the null object is in the second line, otherwise, it's in the disabled one ! Good luck !

Comment: Hi there!

The error is in the first of the two lines.
But what should I change?
If I disable the line it will not run like it's supposed to do.

Comment: OK, so verify that line, but why you have attached two listeners for the same `MouseEvent.CLICK` on your `maan.land.blad` object ? You have to use only one ! and inside the handler, you can use `e.target` instead of `maan.land.blad`.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1009 occurs when you're trying to access something that doesn't exist.

So when the user clicks, it moves to another frame, but if the user clicks again it won't be able to execute because the code won't exist anymore. By the error that's being returned we can see that you're program is trying to access the function 'klikblad2()' when it doesn't exist on that frame (but the frame it was previously on).

I recommend adding:

```
whateverTheTargetIs.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventNameHere);
```

To the end of all your functions that go to another frame where the code won't be. This will solve your problem because it won't be listening for clicks anymore meaning it won't try to access a non-existing (on that frame anyway) functions; so it won't return any errors.

Sorry if this seems complicated or hard to understand, just say if you're still confused.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Fixed it!

I changed the order of the functions.

```
maan.land.blad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, klikblad2);
maan.land.blad.buttonMode = true;

function klikblad2(e: Event): void {
    if (maan.land.blad.currentFrameLabel == "heelblad")
    maan.land.blad.gotoAndPlay("130");
    rupsje.gotoAndPlay("293");
}

maan.land.blad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, klikblad);
maan.land.blad.buttonMode = true;

function klikblad(e: Event): void {
    if (maan.land.blad.currentFrameLabel == "halfblad")
    this.gotoAndStop(1, "Cocon2");
}
```